# How to check android app first run - Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I am using cordova for my android application. I have lots of pages, and my main or homepage is the index.html. How can I check if it's the first time the user to land to the homepage from opening the app (regardless of how many times he clicked and open the app on different time). I just want to check if it is the first time he access the index.html after he opened the app since he can navigate back to homepage anytime from other pages. I'm using cordova and angularjs

Comment: Well you can save his IMEI number and compare at the load event. If in your DB the IMEI doesn't exist then its the first time.

Comment: put a flag in index.html. store that flag to locastorage when he access your index.htm, next time check if that flag exist or not. if it exist then it's not the first time he access index.html else it's the first time. btw index.html is the start page for cordova. so whenever an app starts it will definetly gonna load. PS: localStore is not that persistent as compared to sqlite etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the deviceready event you can make use of localStorage like this.

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") != 1) {
// Running for the first time.
window.localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", 1);
console.log("1st time");
}
else
{
//Already run this app before.
console.log("running this for more than one time");
}
```

or use sqlite and store your values like this in a db and check it everytime you opens up the app.

sessionStorage Will be cleared each time you exit the app,

```
var keyName = window.sessionStorage.key(0); //Get key name
window.sessionStorage.setItem("key", "value"); //Set item
var value = window.sessionStorage.getItem("key");// Get item
window.sessionStorage.removeItem("key"); //Remove Item 
window.sessionStorage.clear();//Clear storage
```

Comment: But when using localStorage, it would still be present in the next launching of the app. Is it possible to use sessionStorage so whenever the app is closed then open the app again, it would still first time to access the index?

Comment: see edited answer, you can implement the session store logic also.

Comment: sessionStorage example is PERFECT for one of my needs!  Been searching for a way to do this for awhile, awesome!